# How to force-expand a \def for \in@?

Tags: conditionals, expansion

Take the following code as an example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\def\myvar{foobar}

\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\in@{foo}{foobar}\ifin@ Yes\else No\fi,
\in@{foo}{\myvar}\ifin@ Yes\else No\fi
\makeatother
\end{document}
```

This typesets `Yes, No` while I would expect `Yes, Yes`. I'm guessing this is because `\myvar` is not being expanded before `\in@` does its work. How do I make it work?

<sub>Note: I'm not very good at expansion, so it may be that the above (or the title) doesn't make much sense.</sub>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Several ways, one way to do it with two `\expandafter` is

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\def\myvar{foobar}

\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\in@{foo}{foobar}\ifin@ Yes\else No\fi,
\def\zz{\in@{foo}}
\expandafter\zz\expandafter{\myvar}\ifin@ Yes\else No\fi
\makeatother
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

`\in@` doesn't expand its arguments; you can easily define a new macro `\ein@` that expands (once) its argument:

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\myvar{foobar}

\makeatletter
\def\ein@#1#2{%
  \expandafter\ein@@\expandafter{#2}{#1}%
}
\def\ein@@#1#2{\in@{#2}{#1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\in@{foo}{foobar}\ifin@ Yes\else No\fi,
\ein@{foo}{\myvar}\ifin@ Yes\else No\fi
\makeatother

\end{document}
```

You can do it more easily with `xparse`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\IfInTF}{smmmm}
 {
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
    {
     \tl_if_in:onTF { #3 } { #2 }  { #4 } { #5 }
    }
    {
     \tl_if_in:nnTF { #3 } { #2 }  { #4 } { #5 }
    }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand\myvar{foobar}


\begin{document}

\IfInTF{foo}{foobar}{Yes}{No},
\IfInTF*{foo}{\myvar}{Yes}{No}

\end{document}
```