# Expansion of an optional parameter for an environment

Tags: hyperref, captions, environments, expansion

I want to define a custom environment, which takes an optional parameter, and I want be able to link to the environment using `nameref`. To this end, I tried something similar to the following MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{trace}

\newenvironment{myenv}[1][]
{
  % define auxiliary variable, as #1 is not allowed in the end part of a newenvironment
  \def\myarg{#1} 
}
{
  \captionof{table}{\myarg}
}


\begin{document}
\begin{myenv}[A title.\label{myenv:title}]
Something that pretends to be a table.
\end{myenv}

\traceon
\nameref{myenv:title}
\traceoff

\end{document}
```

Tracing shows hyperref is defining the following macro:

```latex
\r@myenv:title ->{1}{1}{\myarg \relax }{table.1}{}
```

which, predictably, gives me an

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \myarg
```

I guess that makes sense, as \myarg is only defined in the scope of the environment. My question is now: How do I force \myarg to expand before it is passed to `\r@myenv:title`?

I have already taken a look at [a similar question about expansion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/287891/how-to-force-expand-a-def-for-in), but was not able to adapt that solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using `xparse`'s `\NewDocumentEnvironment` you can use the arguments in the end part directly. In the code below I used `\IfValueT` to check whether the optional argument was given at all and only then use the `\caption`. If you don't do this check you're setting an empty caption each time you omit the optional argument. Another option would be to use a mandatory argument in the first place, as you're directly forwarding it to `\caption` (this would be done with `\NewDocumentEnvironment{myenv}{ m }` instead of `o`).

Unrelated note: `hyperref` should be loaded as the last package in your document (there are a few exceptions to this rule of thumb, e.g. `cleveref` should be loaded after it).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{trace}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{myenv}{ o }
{}
{%
  \IfValueT{#1}{\captionof{table}{#1}}%
}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\begin{myenv}[A title.\label{myenv:title}]
Something that pretends to be a table.
\end{myenv}

\traceon
\nameref{myenv:title}
\traceoff

\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, I am actually sending the argument through \ifdefstring first, just left it out for the sake of the MWE.

Comment: @KonstantinKotenko you should also make sure to put a `%` after an opening brace, that would otherwise include a space in your code.

Answer (score 4):

The key is to expand `\myarg` in the closing part of your environment definition.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{trace}

\newenvironment{myenv}[1][]
{
  % define auxiliary variable, as #1 is not allowed in the end part of a newenvironment
  \def\myarg{#1} 
}
{
  \def\tmp{\captionof{table}}%
  \expandafter\tmp\expandafter{\myarg}
}


\begin{document}
\begin{myenv}[A title.\label{myenv:title}]
Something that pretends to be a table.
\end{myenv}

\traceon
\nameref{myenv:title}
\traceoff

\end{document}
```

[image]